# Unable to connect to local neo4j data store in Graphileon InterActor

Tags: docker, neo4j, graphileon

I am trying to setup Graphileon InterActor on my local machine to try it out. I am following this guide:
http://docs.graphileon.com/interactor/Getting_started/Setup_InterActor/Installation.html
When running InterActor for the first time, I'm redirected to the InterActor Settings page, where I'm prompted to enter user credentials as well as the connection settings of my Neo4j instance.

Since I am using docker, I have configured Neo4j to allow connections from outside localhost.

However, I still get an error: Could not connect. Neo4j error: Can't open connection to http://172.17.0.1:7474/db/data/ while trying to "Test Connection".

[image]

Comment: and do you have access to this url with a browser : `http://172.17.0.1:7474/browser` ?

Comment: Its been a month, Not sure whether the issue fixed. Try binding the port with -p 7474:7474 when running docker image. Because in the link you shared, they made port binding to 8080:80. You could check that!

Answer (score 1):

with the new [Graphileon Personal Edition](https://graphileon.com/graphileon-personal-edition/) these kind of problems belong to the past :)